# Is there a way to remove the calculation of length norms for fields in elastic search?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

**`lengthNorm` is one of the three factors going into calculating the norm for a field.**

In elastic search, one can turn off field normals with `"omit_norms" : true`

Unfortunately, this causes no index-time boost to be applied when querying against such fields.

**Is there some way to strictly turn off the calculation of `lengthNorm`?**

I need field-level index-time boost, but I really need the length of the field not to matter.

[**Reference**](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lengthNorm and field level boosting, as you said, are both stored in the `norm`. So no, you can't have one without the other.

But you don't actually need field boosting at index time.  You can apply it at search time instead, and that way you have more flexibility when you want to tweak the boost level later on.

Not only that, by setting `omit_norms` you reduce the amount of data you have to store at index time by quite a lot, so it is to be recommended where appropriate (such as in your case).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess it depends somewhat on how expensive it is to determine field-level boost at query time, but I certainly see your point. Much Appreciated.

Comment: It's not expensive at all. No norm needs to be loaded. It's just a constant which gets factored into the score (eg `_score * 5`), so it's a real win.

Comment: I understand, but I didn't communicate that well. In certain situations (such as mine), the boost needs to be different per the contents of the document. That number can be expensive to determine at query time. Example: Certain tags are more important than others, where tags might be a multi-value field of the main document. So if the "dog" tag is very important, but the "animal" tag is weak (due to being too generic), that is hard to account for.

Comment: The example you mention (with `animal`  being more generic) would be handled by inverse doc frequency.  But I'm guessing that your real situation is more complex than that.

Comment: Yes I tried to post a generic example, because my situation is a bit arcane. I do think I may be able to do something a bit tricky with scoring to solve my problem in a somewhat satisfactory fashion. If I turn off norms and frequency `(index_options : docs)`, I get constant scoring for tags. If I can isolate scoring for my tags, I can use a secondary sort (or scoring adjustments) after ElasticSearch feeds me the results. For example, as a starting point I could secondary sort by document (or tag) boost, since tags-based scoring will be identical. Overly simplified, but a starting point.